# Changing Rows Border color in Excel Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, range

With help, I built a macro to resize tables. When the table is resized to add rows, the borders of the new rows come in the wrong color.

I got to this point. If I can get the rows loop to work, I would make another loop for the columns, to refresh the formatting for both. The bottom row border of the data body (above the totals row) should not change, and the totals row should not be affected at all.

It tells me I cannot use: s.ListRows(x).Borders(xlEdgeTop) - but I need a way to target the table. What should I do?

```
Set r = Worksheets("Proposed").Range("Proposed[Strategy/Type]")
i = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(r, "Dividend")
i = i + 13
Set s = Worksheets("Dividend").ListObjects("Dividend")
s.Resize Range("$A$12:$J$" & i)
For x = 1 To s.ListRows.Count
    With s.ListRows(x).Borders(xlEdgeTop)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ThemeColor = 1
    .TintAndShade = -0.149906918546098
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
Next x
```

Comment: What exactly is the error you got?

Comment: Object doesn't support this property or method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pertinent to you case, refer to the solution shown below (for quick prototyping I was using narrow 12...20 `Rows(x)` range - replace it with your actual upper bound calculated as `s.ListRows.Count`:

```
For x = 12 To 20
    With Rows(x)
        With .Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .Weight = xlThin
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        End With
    End With
Next x
```

Better solution is to apply border styling to entire range without looping through the rows, as shown in the following sample:

```
With Range("A12:J" & 20)
    With .Borders(xlTop)
        .Weight = xlThin
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        '.ThemeColor = 1
        .TintAndShade = -0.149906918546098
    End With
End With
```

In both cases, just replace upper bound "20" with your calculated `s.ListRows.Count`.

Hope this may help.

Comment: I added s.ListRows.Count (in place of 20) and s.ListRows(x) (in place of Rows(x)). It doesn't like the - With .Borders(xlTop) line. Same error as before.

Comment: No, you should use Rows(x) as shown, just replace 20 with s.ListRows.Count.

Comment: It works, but it adds the formatting to all rows in the worksheet. Is there anyway to narrow it to just the listobject?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help by the way! I really appreciate it. I helps me out a lot. I've been spending a lot of time on this issue.

Comment: Yes, I just extended the answer with the second solution: use the Range object as shown.

Comment: You are welcome! I am glad it works for you. Please mark the answer accepted if you are satisfied with the solution. Good luck with your project. Best regards,

Comment: Very helpful! Many thanks. FYI - I added .LineStyle = xlNone (before the list of other border style commands I was using in my original question. Some of the rows already had borders. The borders needed to be erased before I could change the style.

Comment: That's fine, you can further customize the solution as per your requirements. Best regards,